# Some browsers (Safari 4.0.02 & MSIE 8.0) re-url-encode the query string for a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, xmlhttprequest

Inspecting my webserver's logs, i see that some of the AJAX requests being sent, get re-url-encoded by some browsers (or the proxys on the way??):

The original request (which is sent correctly by the vast majority of the browsers is:
GET /somedir/3&4=100&z=3 HTTP/1.1

But on some cases (which by the user-agent i can only attributes to the above mentioned browsers) the requests are sent as:
GET /somedir/3%264=100%26z=3 HTTP/1.1

For some reason, the ampersand sign gets encoded after i supply the information to the XMLHttpRequest object.

Here is the code i use:

```
    var data = document.location.href + params.command;  // single character, alphanumeric

    if ( typeof( params.param ) != "undefined" )
    {
        data += '=' + encodeURIComponent( params.param );
    }

    data += "&0" + "=" + this.someNum + "&z=" + ( this.requestNum++ );
    xhr.open( "GET", data, true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );

    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;  // Defined elsewhere

    if ( xhr.overrideMimeType )
    {
            xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain" );
    }

    xhr.send( null );
```

Some remarks:

1. The requests are always GET requests.
2. The parameters are send as a query string (name1=val1&name2=val2 etc.) without the leading question mark ('?').
3. The names of the parameters are alphanumeric ([a-z0-9]).
4. The parameters values are always encodeURIComponent()-ed (when the value is not numeric).
5. Sometimes the requests get sent as HTTP/1.0 (i think this is a proxy thing...).
6. The user-agent strings which are consistent with this issue:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2)

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en_US) AppleWebKit/530.19.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Dreamweaver/11.0.0.4909 Version/4.0.2 Safari/530.19.2

Solved:
My problem was that i didn't use the query string character ('?') trying to save a character in the trasfers... once i've added the question mark and the URLs looked like: domain.com/?param=value&param2=value everything worked.
Seems like skipping this character might confuse some browsers/proxy servers into thinking the param=value&param2=value are part of the requested page name and therefore escape the '&'s.

Comment: Why don't you do `var data = document.location.href + '?' + params.command;`?

Comment: See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738 2.2. URL Character Encoding Issues.